# Rails 4 Deleting comments belonging to a certain post

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with deleting all comments belonging to a post that is also about to be deleted.

```
  def delete_post
    @alibaba = params[:alibaba]
    if @alibaba == "true"
      @to_delete_post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @comments_deleted = Main.where(post_id: params[:id]).all
      @comments_deleted.destroy
      @to_delete_post.destroy
      redirect_to admin_path
    elsif @alibaba == "false"
      @to_delete_post = PostMotivation.find(params[:id])
      @comments_deleted = Main.where(post_motivation_id: params[:id]).all
      @comments_deteled.destroy
      @to_delete_post.destroy
      redirect_to admin_path
    end
  end
```

Now, when I run above code I have one error:

```
undefined method `destroy' for #<Array:0x007fb9900654b8>"
```

Now , when I take out both lines with @comments_deleted, then everything is fine, post is deleted from my database, but all comments belonging to that posts are still there, and I don't want to delete then by hand every time I delete a post.

Why doesn't my application want to delete all comments belonging to a doomed post?
Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: have you written in Post model has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relation `has_many` in `Post` model, you can set a `dependent` option to remove all associated comments

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

This way you can simplify the function:

```
def delete_post
  if params[:alibaba]
    Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  else
    PostMotivation.find(params[:id]).destroy
  end
  redirect_to admin_path
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't "delete" an array.  You can delete each record in an array.

But you might find it easer if you replace the two lines with...

```
Main.delete_all("post_id = ?", params[:id])
```

And (on the `@alibaba == 'false'`)

```
Main.delete_all("post_motivation_id = ?", params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using delete_all, you probably want to use destroy_all to make sure the record is removed. So instead of having

```
Main.where(post_id: params[:id]).all,
```

you should make @comments_deleted to be

```
Main.where("post_id = ?", params[:id]) and do @comments_deleted.destroy_all
```

to remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. first, you use Post.find(params[:id]) to retrieve the post you want to delete.
2. second you use @comment = @post.comments.where(post_id: @post.id) to retrieve all the comments that related to the post you deleted, where statment retrieve all results not only the first occurrence.
3. finally, you loop on these comments and destroy them.

   ```
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @comment = @post.comments.where(post_id: @post.id) 
   @comment.each do |comment|
       comment.destroy
   end
   ```